# displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar fails in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios8.3

I use

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

to display the `searchBar` in the `navigationBar`. This used to work great, except that in iOS 8.3 the `searchBar` does not appear anymore.

I still use the `UISearchDisplayController` as I want my app to support iOS 7. My understanding is that even though a class is deprecated, it should still work in subsequent OS versions.

Has anyone noticed this as well and perhaps solved it?

Comment: ya its not working....so from 8.3 i am using `UIBarButtonItem` approach

Comment: Thanks @Bhavin. Could you elaborate on your solution? When you add a searchBar manually into the navigation bar, how do you handle the search results table? I tried doing this, but the table (as an overlay) does not appear as it did with `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar`. Would you mind providing your solution code?